# How can implement Flurry Analytics for RokuSG?

Tags: flurry, roku, scenegraph, flurry-analytics, ott

I was unable to find the SDK for Roku.

Please tell me whether Flurry Analytics SDK is available for RokuSG or not?

If there aren't any SDK's, then please suggest me a way to implement it without the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Roku does not support Flurry Analytics. As far as I know there are three options for analytics in Roku---

1. If your intention is basic analytics, Roku provides basic statistics, like installs, visits, streaming data,  BrightScript crashes, buffering data etc, about published channel at developer dashboard. You can access it by clicking the “View Analytics” option for any channel seen on the Manage My Channels page of your Developer Dashboard.  Remember that this information is available for public channels only. You can find more information here--
   https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/develop/platform-features/analytics-support
2. Using Roku Analytics component library. This library implements Google Analytics, Omniture, Brightcove, and Ooyala Analytics. Its quite easy to implement. You can implement one or more of these analytics solutions. Please check Implementation details at below link--
   https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/libraries/roku-analytics-component.md
3. Third and my favorate way is custom implementation of Analytics component, which can be implemented using REST api calls. This is best as you can decide when and for which events you want to capture analytics. Initially it will seem dificult, but once you will dirty your hand in it, you will not go for any other solution.